# toolTip1 не отображает

Tags: c#, winforms

Добавил компонент toolTip1 в проект, написал для него в свойстве каждой кнопки "Tooltip on Tooltip1" нужный текст, но отображения почему то не происходит, в чем может быть проблема.

```
this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
this.toolTip1.OwnerDraw = false;
this.toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
this.toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
this.toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1000;
this.toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;
```

Comment: Вы инициализировали тултип, а добавление его к объекту где?

Comment: Я же написал что в свойствах каждой кнопки указал к примеру this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, "Смена цвета фона");

Comment: можете псевдокод там где вы присваивайте тул тип к объекту